# How can I get page data that I could get with DevTools but using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, html, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to get data(exchange rates) from url https://www.chinamoney.com.cn/english/bmkcpr/ which i am getting with DevTools but when i use this code below i am getting html code equal to "viesource" code. Is there a solution to this problem?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.GetAsync("https://www.chinamoney.com.cn/english/bmkcpr/");

if (!resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

await using Stream stream = await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, true);

string stringResponse = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

Console.WriteLine(stringResponse);
```

Comment: Just fetching an URL only gets you the base page before includes are added and script code runs.  Read up on "scraping with C#" and you might want to use something like Selenium that lets you automate a browser using code